# Monitor a CAN message

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I have a script with CAN signals A,B and C. All the signals are periodic. I want to send signal C depending on the value of A and B. Is there a way to monitor CAN signals via CAPL (Trying to monitor real time data).
Suppose if I want to perform an operation shown below

```
if Signal A==0x04 AND/OR Signal B==0x01    then 

output(signal C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ((getSignal(SignalA)==0x04) && (getsignal(SignalB)==0x01)) output(**MessageofSignalC**);

Note: You have to send out the entire message containing the signal itself (I do not know advanced Communication Protocols sending only signals, and not frames as a Data Unit in Data Link Layer).

- && operand is for logical AND
- || operand is for logical OR

If you have to modify the SignalC, you must do it before sending out its message output(MessageSignalC).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes, we will have to modify the output signal before sending.